# When can symbols be used to represent columns in spark sql?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider a basic `groupBy` expression on a `DataFrame`:

```
val groupDf  = rsdf.groupBy("league","vendor").agg(mean('league),mean('vendor))
```

The `groupBy` portion is fine: it is using strings for column names.  However the `agg` (/`mean`) is *not* - since apparently `Symbol` were not supported here.

I am wondering why `Symbol`'s do not work here - and when they *are* permitted in Spark SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is **never**. There are no `DataFrame` methods which support `Symbols` directly.

The long answers is **everywhere, where Spark compiler expects `Column`**, but you'll need additional objects in scope.

The only reason why Symbols work at all is implicit conversion from `Symbol` to `Column` provided [`SQLImplicits.implicits`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits).

Once imported, compiler will be able to cast `Symbol`, whenever `Column` is required, including `agg` (and implicits are in the scope):

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq((1, 2)).toDF("league", "vendor")

df.groupBy("league","vendor").agg(mean('league),mean('vendor)).show

+------+------+-----------+-----------+                                         
|league|vendor|avg(league)|avg(vendor)|
+------+------+-----------+-----------+
|     1|     2|        1.0|        2.0|
+------+------+-----------+-----------+
```